# How do I identify which log is incorrectly rotated?

Tags: 14.04, cron, email, logging, logrotate

I'm receiving email prompts from two Ubuntu 14.04 servers around unusual `logrotate` behaviour. I don't have any packages installed which are not installed on other servers which don't exhibit this behaviour.

The email subject contains this line:

```
test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

So it seems related to cron.daily. I have not edited anything in cron.daily.
The message is:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping
```

How can I find which log file is causing this?

Edit:I only get these messages on a Monday morning, which leads me to believe it's on with a weekly directive.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/a/861496/334516, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32045778/2072269

Comment: Thanks @muru , I had searched it, but didn't find anything as sensible as these two answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to turn on verbosity on logrotate. We need more information on which line causing this error.

Edit `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. At the end of the file there is line `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`, change this to `/usr/sbin/logrotate --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf`.

Or else you might run this directly `/usr/sbin/logrotate --verbose /etc/logrotate.conf`, but of course some logs will be get rotated if the conditions matching the config file rules for rotation.

Comment: I'd already done this, based on the linked answer by muru, will the verbose output appear in the email?

Comment: @Arronical by right, you should see the verbosity in the mail as well. You also can look into logrotate.d directory and focus on files that get rotates weekly. i.e containing `rotate 7` line.